# gem installed in directory of different patchlevel

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

After updating from *ruby-1.8.7-p352* to *ruby-1.8.7-p358* via *rvm*, gems are still installed to the path of *ruby-1.8.7-p352*.

`$GEM_PATH` is set correctly but `rvm gemdir` is wrong.

```
# rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p358
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358
# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
# echo $GEM_PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global
# rvm gemdir
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352
```

Installing gems works without errors but the location of the gem is wrong and binaries can't be executed.

```
# gem instll bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.3
1 gem installed
# bundle
bash: bundle: command not found
# which bundle
/usr/bin/which: no bundle in (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
# gem which bundler
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler
```

I tried `export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358` but `rvm gemdir` still shows the path to *p358* and gems are installed to this path.

Comment: please add gist of `rvm --trace gemdir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the rubygems solved the problem:

```
# rvm rubygems latest
```